# Got a Hexadecimal "Name" Generator for fills?

Tags: memory, hex

I was debugging the other day and came across some memory- and register-fills I hadn't seen before on some embedded hardware I'm using. So I started a mental catalog. For example:

```
DEADBEEF, BAADF00D, D15EA5ED, DECEA5ED, BAA5H33P...
```

Something that sticks out when you look at the memory viewer and is vaguely related to what it's about (deleted memory, no-man's land, outerwear...).

It got me thinking - is there a generator for these? Something like a l33t name generator except limited to hex numbers (hexits?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ grep -i '^[abcdefols]*$' /usr/share/dict/words | tr ols 015
abaca
abed
abe1e
ab1
ab1e
ab0de
ab0ded
acc
accede
acceded
.
.
.

0ff
0ffa1
0ffed
0ff10ad
0ff10aded
01de
01e0
```

Comment: grep -i '^[abcdefolst]*$' /usr/share/dict/words | tr olst 0157

Answer (score 2):

**BAA5H33P**??

It contains both an **H** and a **P**? 
Those aren't valid hex digits.

You missed Java's famous **[CAFEBABE](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/whyCAFEBABE.html)**

You can read more on it at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak), including :
**CAB1E** (cable)
**FACE**
**BEAD**
**C0ED**
etc, etc....

Comment: While we're on the subject of Java, I like 0xDECAFBAD :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha! "Hexspeak" was the keyword I needed for the Googles.

Here is a [Python program](http://reminiscential.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/hexspeak-and-generator/) to find all Hexspeak words. And a [list](http://reminiscential.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/hexspeak-word-list/) of what that program found.

Answer (score 0):

My brain is fuzzy today, but this works. Alter to taste...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
letters = {'A':'A', 'B':'B', 'C':'C', 'D':'D', 'E':'E', 'F':'F', 'I':'1', 'O':'0', 'S':'5'}
f = open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line[:-1]
    if len(line) < 4:
        continue
    word = ""
    goodword = True
    for c in list(line):
        if c.upper() not in letters.keys():
            goodword = False
        else:
            word += letters[c.upper()]
    if goodword:
        print "%20s\t%s" % (line,word)
f.close()
```